# with svn, check the revision number when offline

Tags: svn, version-control, revision, offline-mode

I'm offline (well, to be exact my svn repository in unreachable right now), but I have a fully fledged working copy on which I am, well, working :-)

Now I need to know the revision number of a file. How can I check the revision number of a particular file (which by the way doesn't have the `svn:keywords` property) while being offline?

I usually check them with `svn ls -v` or `svn log | head` or `svn blame` (of course they give more than I'm looking for right now).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use: `svn info FILENAME`

Answer (score 1):

You can also enter the folder .svn and check the file named entries, you'll see the revision number and the author